# Does PHP take RAM when defining variable from variable and taking instance of object to another variable?

Tags: php, performance, variables

In case I have this code

```
<?php
$array = array();
for ($i=1;$i<100000;$i++){
    $array[$i] = md5(rand(0,9999999999999999));
}

$array2 = $array;
```

`$array` takes about 0.5MB RAM, let's say. Does PHP proccess take about 1.0MB RAM with `$array2 = $array;` ? and in this case

```
<?php
class rand{
    public $array;
    function rand(){
        $this->array = array();
        for ($i=1;$i<100000;$i++){
            $this->array[$i] = md5(rand(0,9999999999999999));
        }

    }
}

$class = new rand();
$class2 = $class;
```

`$class` takes about 0.5MB RAM, let's say
. Does PHP proccess take 1.0MB with `$class2 = $class`?

is it same?

Tests:

- [First](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/5d646.php)
- [Second](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/f9c5c.php)

Comment: Check it out for yourself. See get_memory_usage()

Comment: @JohnCartwright: Wow. It looks it's not copying themselves. Look [first](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/62669.php), [second](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/aee4d.php)

Comment: @genesis: You need to write another get_memory_usage() for the first variable, array or object. Your code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oops, I meant memory_get_usage()

Comment: @Jitamaro: see my question edited. It is testing exact code I have in question

Comment: I assume this is a caching strategy, try this **before** the second memory_get_usage(): array_pop($array2); the memory increases rapidly, why? because php caches the copy of the array as a reference as long as you do not modify it. If you start modifying it, the array gets copied in the memory. This won't happen with the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the PHP manual in the reference section warns about: the Engine is smart enough. Setting the `$array2 = $array;` does *not* cause duplicate storage, as PHP recognizes they are still both the same. However, try a `$array[2] = 'something;'` after that. PHP detects the difference, and only *then* will copy the values.

```
<?php
$array = array();
for ($i=1;$i<100000;$i++){
    $array[$i] = md5(rand(0,9999999999999999));
}
echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
$array2 = $array;
echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
$array['foo'] = 'bar';
echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
//17252052
//17252156
//23776652
```

Classes are references by default, and only a `clone $object` would result in 2 objects in PHP >= 5.

Comment: How is it possible that it [takes a lot more](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d6771.php) memory for me? extensions?

Comment: is there an option to kill this smart behaviour? I can compile myself!

Comment: @genesis: edited the classes answer in. And why it takes more? There's a random factor of course, but this is from a lean & mean command-line php script, not in a webserver, which is quite a difference.

Comment: @Jitamaro: the C source code of PHP is available, go ahead. I can't for the life of me think _why_ you would destroy this behavior though. There are as of yet no ill sideeffects of this behavior that I know of.

Comment: @genesis: you see you need 3 memory_get_usage!!! I want an upvote now for my post or I delete it!!!

Comment: @Jitamaro: just go ahead deleting. this is better answer. sorry

Comment: [puts on camp voice] Oh,behave! [/back to normal]

Comment: I told him that before he don't believe and he is voting you. It's logic.