# Efficiently implement a very large list, arrays? SPL linked list? anything else?

Tags: php, arrays, list, tree, performance

I have to create an really huge tree to solve the game of peg solitaire.
It has to be in PHP.
Although I have experience in PHP, it's mostly doing web dev, so I have no experience with memory management and large data structures, which I would normally handle in C++, but this is a test for a job.
I will solve it with some kind of backtracking with depth first search, so the tree doesn't get so huge, but at any point in time, I have to have a list of all the open nodes, which I plan to achieve with a simple array of references.
Is this efficient? should I do it with a SPL linked list or something else rather?
I already tested that an array can grow only limited by the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that php handles array and object very efficiently, see here [Does PHP take RAM when defining variable from variable and taking instance of object to another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863206/does-php-take-ram-when-defining-variable-from-variable-and-taking-instance-of-obj/). So maybe a binary tree would be good? You can also make your own extension if you are good in C++.

Answer (score 1):

[HAKMEM item 75](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/games.html#item75) or Ins & Outs of Peg Solitaire (ISBN: 0-19-286145-X).

And don't use arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Also, can you justify your advice against arrays? and what alternative should I use? thanks.

Comment: @Petruza That would be a really bad start from a job applicant. In short http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/why-didnt-they-like-this-code

Comment: Ok, that link shows how poor performance on a test didn't get the job. I understand that. I mean, why do you advice against using arrays in PHP and what alternative should I use instead?